# Making http request inside mongo shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to pull some information out of mongo shell and send it to a remote api server.

Since mongo shell has a embedded javascript interpreter (spider monkey), I tried below code:

```
// myfile.js
db.aggregate([ { $currentOp: {} }])
  .forEach(function(doc) {
      // I want to post each doc to a remote api server.
      let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.open('POST', url);
      http.send(doc);
  })
```

and

```
mongo myfile.js
```

The above method fails. XMLHttpRequest is not defined. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you import the module?

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

Comment: Isn't 'require' a nodejs specific syntax? I just added require statement in the script file but still give errors